Can ring singularities form a Hopf link?
Can ring singularities form a Hopf link?

There may be a more definitive answer to this question, but I believe the answer is that it would be impossible for any astrophysical scenario to generate such a configuration in standard 3+1 GR.
There is a theorem that states that each all event horizons in 3+1 gravity are isomorphic to a 2-sphere (Hawking, Comm. Math. Phys. 25, 152–166 (1972)). So you would necessarily require a merging of the event horizons, which would entail a reduction of the solution to a standard Kerr Black Hole. This might also mean that you couldn't have eternal black holes in 3+1 GR with such a singularity configuration since once you cross the combined event horizon there is ambiguity as to which singularity you end up in.
One interesting option is if you are looking at higher dimensional (4+1) GR theories you can have black rings (Emparan, Reall, Phys. Rev., 88, 101101. (2002)). The higher dimensional space would allow these rings to cross "over" each other without intersecting, forming something that would be a Hopf link when projected into 3+1 space.
